# ASP.NET|Process Class- Runing And Stoping Process

Tags: c#, asp.net

few days ago, my freind asked me to build him a proagram that start and stop process.

so, as easy as it is. i did the next code:

```
(using System.Diagnostics)

Process process;
process = Process.start("SOMEONE.exe");
Process.Kill();
```

Now, thats it the easy part. everything works. but. when i do the same code in asp.net, its strat the process, but when you kill the process, nothing happnd. no matter what i did, any one have any solion to the next problem :(?

Comment: Could you please try to be clearer on what exactly the problem is? What do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "nothing happened"? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: its says that the process is not ruining, but it is.. "The Process has exit." but its still runing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx):

> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill
>   method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit,
>   or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has
>   exited.

Comment: Don't expect the process to be in run state immediately after calling process.Start(). Ensure it is running and only then try to kill it. Explore the properties of process in debug mode inside VS, after you called process.Start().

Comment: i have waited about 15 mintues. the process is runing. i am sure 100%. but its not "killing" it. its says "The Process has exit" but NOTHING happnd.

Comment: Works for me... exactly as your example (besides the variable that should be process and not Process in the 2nd and 3rd line). I don't know everything else...

Answer (score 0):

AppPool in IIS needs to run under LOCAL Account - otherwise ASP.NET doesn't have enough rights to start/stop processes on the server.